# siteUrl in Twig templates not working

Tags: localization, siteurl

I've got a problem where `siteURL` wasn't working for a localized version of my site. I have a site in two languages — Russian and English, with Russian exposed under `www.mysite.com` and English under `www.mysite.com/en/`.

My problem was that `siteUrl` variable was always giving me a non localized version of the site URL (`www.mysite.com` instead of `www.mysite.com/en/`) on the pages in English, even though other localized features were working fine (strings were translated into English, correct entries output etc.). See below for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is that in the `general.php` I had a setup which somehow was giving trouble when setting `siteUrl`. Things were like this:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    ),
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'ru' => 'http://www.mysite.com/',
        'en_us' => 'http://www.mysite.com/en/'
    )
);
```

While seemingly correct, in this setup `siteUrl` should be moved into `'*'` block, otherwise there comes the problem that I described earlier. So the correct version is this:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'siteUrl' => array(
            'ru' => 'http://www.issuesinlinguistics.ru/',
            'en_us' => 'http://www.issuesinlinguistics.ru/en/'
        )
    )
);
```